# Should I accept a job offer where I am supposed to use technologies as VB 6, ASP (Old), SQL Server

Tags: software-industry, new-job, technology

I've been working in a small firm (<10 Employees) using the technologies such as **VB.Net, ASP.Net, SQL Server 2005**.

Now I've got a job offer from a bigger company. But the confusion is that in the offer job I'm supposed to work with technologies such as **VB 6, ASP(old classic)**. Following is my question -

If I work there for one year or so, will this experience be good for my profile and will I get any opportunities for these old technologies (do people still use them)?

Comment: Questions here need to deal with real constructive issues.  This is at best an opinion poll.  You have not provided us enough information about you to answer it.  and If you did provide that information then the question would be to localized.  What is you concern about taking the new position?

Comment: @Chad well i'm confused that's why i'm asking you people :)

Comment: But you have not really provided us with the infromation to answer it for you.  Why are you considering the new offer?  Money, you enjoy that work more, location, current job is ending soon?  What do you want to do? Those are questions we can not fill in for you.  I suspect once you answer them then you will no longer need our help.

Answer (score 5):

It's a classic question of specialization.

I have a great deal of Lotus Notes experience - a technology that is greatly loved by a very small community and pretty well dismissed by everyone else.  If I chose to headlight those skills, I could get jobs very, very easily in a very, very small pond.  As the number of people with that expertise dwindles, it becomes more and more lucrative for the few people still using it - but it limits you at the same time.

The question you have to ask yourself is whether or not you want to play that game or play the game of being the best on a wide range of new technologies. In other words, are you going to go broad or go deep.  Going broad has the advantage of allowing you to advance in terms of leadership (if not necessarily salary) and in my case, helps me to sleep at night, knowing that when the last Lotus Notes shop moves to something else, I don't have a massive retraining.  (And no, I haven't used my Lotus Notes background for about 3 years now).

On the other hand, if you like to stay put and go deep on one thing, you could do a lot worse than VB6. Sure, it's nearing EOL, but as recently as 2009, [87% of companies](https://web.archive.org/web/20200923121701/http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/02/18/results-of-the-visual-basic-survey-part-2-visual-basic.aspx) were still using it.  There will be VB6 apps around for a long time, in the same way COBOL is still out there.

Will you have the pick of jobs anywhere? No. But will you have security? Sure.

Answer (score 3):

I've tangled with this one many-a-time.  It's a trade-off question.  Do the benefits associated with gaining experience with the new firm on old technology outweigh the benefits associated with using the same technology with your current firm, or newer technology with a firm x after an assumed-to-be-arriving offer.

This was always my answer: if you want to stay in development over the long-haul, try to get experience with newer technology; certainly do not regress.  If, on the other hand, you want to move into management (or whatever), the value attached to working with the firm could potentially outweigh the benefits of working with newer technology.  Be sure to accurately weigh the other implicit costs of joining the new firm, though.  For example, a company that refuses to move beyond VB and ASP can't be that forward-looking of an organization.  Getting into management with this firm might not be worth the costs of signing on.  The reputation of the employer goes with you, wherever you go.

I have personally found it difficult to sign on with an organization that wants to stick with old technology, simply because it would drive me crazy.

PS- it might be bad form to actually name the company in these posts.

Comment: well its not that the new firm works with only these technologies only(which i've mentioned) they use mostly all the popular technologies